# Firebase Storage Upload Error: "Object albumNum/1 does not exist."

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

This is my upload code

```
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let albumImageRef = FIRStorage.storage().referenceForURL("gs://tiat-ea6fd.appspot.com")
        .child("albumNum")
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    let newImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 3.0)
    self.metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
    print("\(values + 1)")
    albumImageRef.child("\(values + 1)").putData(newImage!, metadata: self.metadata){metadata, error in
        if error == nil {self.collectionView.reloadData()}
        else {print(error?.localizedDescription)}

    }

}
```

When I run the code it says

```
Optional("Object albumNum/1 does not exist.")
```

and there is nothing in my database

Comment: Do you have a image named "1" without a file extension,  in the directory "albumNum"?

Comment: Also, Have you verified that newImage is actually creating a valid jpeg?

Answer (score 0):

What type is your `values` object?

If it's of type `Int?` (optional integer) or some other optional type you can try unwrapping it before you call `.putData` on the `albumImageRef.child("\(values + 1)")` reference:

```
guard let values = values else { return }
```

Comment: values is a Int